# Open many files in a folder apply a macro and save them to a different folder with different names like 1, 2, 3

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write code on VBA that allows me to access all files in a predetermined folder 1. Open each file, apply a macro of interest, then copy the end result to a different workbook in a predetermined folder 2 save them there as .csv files

The problem with my code is that it is a problem when I am saving the workbook added to the predetermined folder 2. I am always saving it with the same name which creates an overlapping.

The other problem is when I try to close wb.close (see my code below) I am  getting the save changes y/n prompt.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyD9n.jpg)

I already wrote a code and failed miserably. I need expert help. Thank you again for all your support.

Best
Rami

```
Sub LoopFile()
    'Enable reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime if you want to use early binding
    Dim fso As Object  'Scritping.FileSystemObject
    Dim fldr As Object 'Scripting.Folder
    Dim file As Object 'Scripting.File
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fldr = fso.GetFolder("D:\Rami Chehab\University Degrees & Courses\PhD in Labour Economics\Data\Data 2016\UNCTAD\1\nOT DONE COUNTRIES\")

    For Each file In fldr.Files
        'Open the file
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(file.Path)
        '## You will need to modify this line to refer to the correct
        '    module name and macro name:
        Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!Ramroum"
        Cells.Select
        Range("F7").Activate
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Workbooks.Add
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        ' The problem here it is only saving the folder as name 1 and not changing for example for 1 then in the other loop to 2, 3 and so on and so forth
        ' I think I need your help here in my code
        ChDir _
            "D:\Rami Chehab\University Degrees & Courses\PhD in Labour Economics\Data\Data 2016\UNCTAD\Okay"
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
            "D:\Rami Chehab\University Degrees & Courses\PhD in Labour Economics\Data\Data 2016\UNCTAD\Okay\1.xlsx" _
            , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
        ActiveWindow.Close
        'Close the file (it was saved in Macro6 already)
        wb.Close
    Next

    Set file = Nothing
    Set fldr = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Replace `wb.close` with `wb.Close SaveChanges:=True` to save changes before closing workbook.

Comment: I do not want to save changes I just want to exit without saving and I want to not save without every time telling excel I do not want to save

Answer (score 0):

I think I did something to a certain extent right and here is my new code. However, I still can not tell excel not to ask me whether you like to save the file or not when I write wb.close

Anyways here is my code

```
Sub Ram2()
'Enable reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime if you want to use early binding
    Dim fso As Object  'Scritping.FileSystemObject
    Dim fldr As Object 'Scripting.Folder
    Dim file As Object 'Scripting.File
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fldr = fso.GetFolder("D:\Rami Chehab\University Degrees & Courses\PhD in Labour Economics\Data\Data 2016\UNCTAD\1\nOT DONE COUNTRIES\")

    For Each file In fldr.Files
        'Open the file
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(file.Path)
        '## You will need to modify this line to refer to the correct
        '    module name and macro name:
        Application.Run "PERSONAL.XLSB!Ramroum"
        Cells.Select
        Range("F7").Activate
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Workbooks.Add
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ' The problem here it is only saving the folder as name 1 and not changing for example for 1 then in the other loop to 2, 3 and so on and so forth
    ' I think I need your help here in my code
        ChDir _
        "D:\Rami Chehab\University Degrees & Courses\PhD in Labour Economics\Data\Data 2016\UNCTAD\Okay"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "D:\Rami Chehab\University Degrees & Courses\PhD in Labour Economics\Data\Data 2016\UNCTAD\Okay\" & CStr(i) & ".xlsx" _
        , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWindow.Close
    i = i + 1


        'Close the file (it was saved in Macro6 already)
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next

    Set file = Nothing
    Set fldr = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Rami, if this code does not solve your problem you should not put it in an "Answer". Click the "Edit" link below your question and add the code to the question, itself, with an explanation. If this code does solve your problem, then click "edit" below this answer and add an explanation of how it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Put Application.DisplayAlerts = False near the top of your Sub. The put Application.DisplayAlerts = True at the end of your sub.